# Calculating this integral

Tags: calculus, integration

This integral has come up in calculating the self inductance of a toroidal coil.

$ \int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{a\sin^2x}{\frac{b}{a}+\cos x} dx$

Where $b$ is the mean radius , while $a$ is the cross-sectional radius.

I'm suspecting complex analysis, but it's beyond my knowledge.

Is there any way to calculate this integral more simply?

Comment: Have you try replacing $\sin^2(x)$ by $1-\cos^2(x)$?

Comment: @ThibautDumont yes, but it doesn't help us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First lower the degree at the numerator,

$$\int\frac{\sin^2(x)}{r+\cos(x)}dx=\int\frac{r^2-\cos^2(x)+1-r^2}{r+\cos(x)}dx=\int\left(r-\cos(x)+\frac{1-r^2}{r+\cos(x)}\right)dx.$$
The first two terms are easy. Then by the substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$,

$$\int\frac{dx}{r+\cos(x)}=\int\frac1{r+\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2}=\int\frac{2\,dt}{r+1+(r-1)t^2}=\frac2{|r-1|}\int\frac{dt}{a^2\pm t^2},$$

with $a^2=(r+1)/|r-1|$.

Depending on the sign of $r-1$ this leads to $$\frac1a\arctan(\frac ta)$$ or $$\frac1a\text{artanh}(\frac ta).$$

or if $r=1$,

$$t.$$

Comment: From the context it seems that $a<b$, so your $r>1$. But +1 for your solution...

Comment: @mickep: I am paving the way to new coil designs :)

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $t = \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For $a>b>0$. Substitute $\cos x = \frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2}$, $\sin x = \frac{z-\frac{1}{z}}{2i}$ and $dx = \frac{dz}{iz}$. Consider the contour $C$ to be the upper half unit circle (since your integral from $0$ to $\pi$). So that the integration becomes 
 $$
\int_0^\pi  {\frac{{a^2 \sin ^2 x}}{{b + a\cos x}}dx}  = \frac{{ai}}{2}\int_C {\frac{{\left( {z^2  - 1} \right)^2 }}{{z^2 }}\frac{1}{{z^2  + 2\frac{b}{a}z + 1}}dz} $$ completing the square in the denumenator and then find the roots inside $C$. After that calculate the residue at the zeros of the denumenator multiply by $2\pi {\rm{i}}$. By Residue theorem we have [image]
$$
\int_C {f\left( z \right)dz}  = \int_{\gamma _r } {f\left( z \right)dz}  + 2\pi i{\mathop{\rm Res}\nolimits} \left\{ {f\left( z \right)} \right\}
$$